# Question about System.in and stream

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

Is there a way to reset System.in so I can have a fresh stream from which to have Scanner wait for input? Here is my code:

```
    boolean run = true;
    String commandLine = "";
    Scanner keyboard;

    Tokenizer arguments;
    RecursiveDescentParser parse;

    while (run){
        // Command prompt
        System.out.print(" ==>\t");

        keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        while (keyboard.hasNextLine()) {
              commandLine += " " + keyboard.nextLine();
        }

        keyboard.close();

        keyboard = null;

        System.setIn ( new FileInputStream ( FileDescriptor.in )  ) ;

        System.setIn(System.in);

        keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        arguments = new Tokenizer(commandLine);
        commandLine = "";
        parse = new RecursiveDescentParser(arguments, false);
        run = parse.parseStartSymbol();
    }           
}
```

Once this program has run once, hasNextLine() will return false indefinitely prompting a question how do I solve this?  Can I reset the stream somehow?  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're looking for:

```
InputStream originalInput = System.in;
System.setIn(new FileInputStream(FileDescriptor.in));
// Do stuff
System.setIn(originalInput);
```

However, it would be a better idea never to replace `System.in`, and just make the rest of your code take an input stream to work with.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more please as to what you mean by making the rest of my code take an input stream to work with.

Comment: @user633658: Well, what's so special about System.in? If you really need to reset it, that suggests you're using it elsewhere. Does that code have to *know* that it's using System.in? Couldn't you pass in System.in as an argument to the constructor or whatever?

Comment: Problem is as the code is I can only read in data from the console or redirected using scanner once and because system.in problems hasNextLine() returns false indefinitely.

Comment: @user633658: But it's not clear why you need to redirect it to read from a file. Why don't you just change the code which is trying to use System.in to use the file directly? What are you trying to achieve by using the file? (And have you tried my suggested change?)

Comment: The code works by gathering console input or a user can redirect input from a file.  This would not be a problem but the limitations of the stream mean console input is a one shot deal so any further user console input fails because of stream.  The code requires consistent user input as this is the front end feeding console input into the main program but being able to do it only once sucks.

Comment: I have tried several of your changes from the first, to passing in a constructor System.in, to calling new objects of a method and all the results are identical.  Once Stream has EOF it is retired and I read a post where the only solution is a JVM restart.

Comment: @user633658: It's still not really clear what you're doing. Could you come up with a short but *complete* program which demonstrates the problem?

Comment: The code I posted exactly encapsulates the problem.  run it for yourself and eliminate lines:                                                       arguments = new Tokenizer(commandLine);
parse = new RecursiveDescentParser(arguments, false);
run = parse.parseStartSymbol();
                                                                     You will find that you can not read input form the console more than once and as soon as you enter console input for the first time and enter CTRL-Z into the console, all you will see is "==>" repeated indefinitely. This is my problem.

Comment: @user633658: And where would I get RecursiveDescentParser from, for example? And what's in the file? As I say, a short but *complete* program would be much simpler. Make it so I can copy, paste, run javac, then run java.

Comment: You don't need any of those methods as they are part of my main program which has nothing to do with this problem.  You can easily run the code snippet above minus the lines I told you take out and you will find you can not repeatedly enter console input.  Why?  Because of system.in

Comment: @user633658: Okay, I think I see the problem now - you hadn't mentioned (until 10 minutes ago) that you were *killing* console input with Ctrl-Z. In that case I'm not surprised you can't get it back afterwards.

Comment: I apologize for that.  I thought of running the code snippet as a thread of execution indefinitely running and I would populate input form the keyboard into a string and pass that into my program

Comment: @user633658: As far as I'm aware, the entire process will just have one stream to the OS, effectively - if that gets severed, you can't reconnect it. I suggest you have a different way of indicating "I'm done for this section" e.g. a pair of blank lines together.

Comment: Good idea. I decided to just spawn stream off as a thread running to serve my needs.  Now I just need to find a way to kill it and the main thread when time to quit.